# Trying to select a specific row using values from 2 different columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset

I have a dataset about the NBA, shape (126314, 23). Two of the columns are named date_game and fran_id. I'm trying to select the row containing the 2/8/04 Warriors game.

I tried:
nba.loc[nba["date_game"] == "2/8/2004"] & nba.loc[nba["fran_id"] == "Warriors"]

but received error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'

not sure what else to try

Comment: `nba.loc[(nba["date_game"] == "2/8/2004") & (nba["fran_id"] == "Warriors")]`